# how to check that there is data to be written into specified fd

Tags: c, linux, unix

Im trying to see whether someone is writing data into sqlite db. I tought about sql_hook but this can be used only in process which is writing to db. In my case one process is writing into db, while other will only wait for notification that something was written. Therefore i tought about using poll and check whether on sqlite db file there is event data to be write. But poll only checks that events:

```
POLLIN
There is data to read.

POLLPRI
There is urgent data to read (e.g., out-of-band data on TCP socket; pseudoterminal master in packet mode has seen state change in slave).

POLLOUT
Writing now will not block.
```

so i tought about checking events `POLLOUT` on fd which i get by using `open` syscall.

First question: if sqlite is using `open` syscall to open db file, will i using `open (int sqlDBFD = open("/var/log.db", O_RDONLY);
)` receive same `fd` as sqlite ? 
Second question, here is piece of code realted to monitor for events on fd:

```
/* thread method */
void run() {
        int result = 0;
        int cur_fd = -1;
        while(1) {
                result = poll(m_fds, m_curr_m_fds_index, m_timeout * 1000);
                //printf("poll result: %d\n", result);
                if (result > 0) {
                        for(int i =0 ; i< m_curr_m_fds_index; i++){
                                cur_fd = m_fds[i].fd;
                                if (cur_fd > 0) {
                                        if (m_fds[i].revents & POLLIN) {
                                                printf("data to be write on descriptor: %d\n", cur_fd);
                                        }
                                        if (m_fds[i].revents & POLLOUT) {
                                                printf("data to be read on descriptor: %d\n", cur_fd);
                                        }
                                }
                        }
                }else {

                        printf("poll result: %d, errno: %d\n", result, errno);

                }
        }
}
```

and output:

```
data to be write on descriptor: 4
data to be write on descriptor: 4
data to be write on descriptor: 4
data to be write on descriptor: 4
data to be write on descriptor: 4
data to be write on descriptor: 4
data to be write on descriptor: 4
data to be write on descriptor: 4
data to be write on descriptor: 4
data to be write on descriptor: 4
data to be write on descriptor: 4
data to be write on descriptor: 4
data to be write on descriptor: 4
data to be write on descriptor: 4
data to be write on descriptor: 4
data to be write on descriptor: 4
data to be write on descriptor: 4
data to be write on descriptor: 4
data to be write on descriptor: 4
data to be write on descriptor: 4
```

This I set timeout to 3 seconds, but I got constantly message above - how to interpret that? Am I on right direction?

Comment: POLLOUT means YOU can write data to the file.  There are no low-level polling to see someone else writing.  You might want to check out "inotify" instead, which sends you events like whether a file was opened, accessed, or modified.

Comment: Even with the same file, and even if the descriptor number matches, each process will have its own file descriptors.  And your poll result doesn't mean data is being written, but that the fd is ready for writing.  Your best bet, if possible, is probably to have the first process explicitly notify the second when it writes to the database.